# How can I get "comma separated" data from .csv file into Json Format on Splunk Web?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-sdk

I have one "Bal_123.csv" file and when I am searching its data on splunk web by providing query " sourcetype="Bal_123.csv" " I am getting latest indexed raw data in comma separated format. But for further operation I need that data in .Json format

Is there any way we can get that data in .Json format itself. I know I can export the data in Json format but I am using Rest call to get data from splunk and I need that Json data on splunk itself.

can anyone help me regarding this?

Comment: Can you post the code where exactly you need the json format ?

Comment: Hi, I am taking the response of rest query from splunk inside JsonObject but since the response I am getting is not of Json type and hence JsonObject is not getting populated

Answer (score 0):

Splunk will parse JSON, but will not display data in JSON format except, as you've already noted, in an export.

You may be able to play with the `format` command to get something close to JSON.
A better option might be to wrap your REST call in some Python that converts the results into JSON.

Comment: I have used format option but only fewdata i.e. the extra parameter I am providing in query is coming in JSON format rest all are still in CSV format. I think I have only option here is to go with Python although it will be time consuming. Thanks Rich